# Getting "Uninstall_Failed_User_Restricted" while removing bloatware from vivo x70 pro+ via ADB

Tags: android, uninstallation

I'm trying to remove bloatware from my Vivo X70pro+ (origin OS) via ADB, but it shows this error message `Uninstall_Failed_User_Restricted`. Some apps i can remove but some i can't (example:- global search, weather, imusic.. are some of them). Someone please help me rectify this problem.

Comment: Once when im trying to disable, then also getting the same error message

Comment: Hey, welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)  of the website, and read [How do I ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing those are system apps which as far as i know, can only be disabled.

I did find a [thread on XDA](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/safe-to-remove-apps-via-adb-for-vivo-x60-pro.4309647/)

Although it's for x60-pro but am sure you can get some useful stuffs.